# How do I make a scrolled tab in a Tcl/TK notebook?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to create a simple spreadsheet interface. A notebook seems like the only way to go, but I need for it to be scrollable, and I can't figure out how to set that up.

I -think- I need to use a canvas, but I'm not having any luck making it work.

Here's what I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/wish

ttk::style configure ENNotebook.TNotebook -tabposition sw
ttk::notebook .n  -width 1000 -height 200 -style ENNotebook.TNotebook
ttk::frame .n.frAlles1
  
# create canvas with scrollbars
canvas .n.frAlles1.c  -xscrollcommand ".n.frAlles1.xscroll set" -yscrollcommand ".n.frAlles1.yscroll set"
ttk::scrollbar .n.frAlles1.xscroll -orient horizontal -command ".n.frAlles1.c xview"
ttk::scrollbar .n.frAlles1.yscroll -command ".n.frAlles1.c yview"
pack .n.frAlles1.xscroll -side bottom -fill x
pack .n.frAlles1.yscroll -side right -fill y
pack .n.frAlles1.c -expand yes -fill both -side top

.n add .n.frAlles1 -text "TabOne" 

ttk::frame .n.frAlles1.c.f1; 

set vlist {} ;# list of cell names
foreach row {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15} {;#
  pack [frame .n.frAlles1.c.f1.row$row] -fill x
  pack [label .n.frAlles1.c.f1.row$row.r$row -text $row -width 4] -side left
  foreach column {a b c d e f g h} {
      set vname $column$row
      variable $vname
      pack [label .n.frAlles1.c.f1.row$row.$column -textvar ${vname} -relief raised -width 16] -side left
  }
}

# place widgets and buttons
.n.frAlles1.c create window 0 0 -anchor nw -window .n.frAlles1.c.f1 

# determine the scrollregion
.n.frAlles1.c configure -scrollregion [.n.frAlles1.c bbox all]

pack .n -fill both -expand yes
```

This creates a notebook with the contents I'm expecting, but the scrollbars always act as if all of the content is displayed.